# Example of Analytic Solution to 2+1D Maxwell Equations with Dirichlet Boundary Conditions

Tags: electromagnetism, computational-physics, maxwell-equations, boundary-conditions

Just curious, could someone point me to an analytic solution to 2+1D Maxwell equation on a rectangular domain with Dirichlet Boundary Conditions. With the pertinent information regarding the boundary conditions/initial condition. I've written some FDTD code - I just want to compare in order to see if I get the theoretical error between my numerical solution and the true solution.

Comment: Since you didn't get an answer, I thought I'd let you know that we have a tag just for TDTD here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/. You're welcome to ask the question again over there if you're still looking for an answer.